# Accessing the second element in my LinkedList, has multiple nodes

Tags: java, list

i am trying to access the patient id of my linkedlist so that i can use a find method to access only that patients record. Since each patient has their own list of elements, i have each list linked to one another.

So far the data looks like this, i am reading it from a text file ->
textfile:

```
Tim He
000001
1001 Square
66
130
03-03-2013
04-05-2014
04-06-2014
Mike rouch
000002
1001 Square
66
130
03-03-2013
04-05-2014
04-06-2014
Luis shin
000003
1001 Square
66
130
03-03-2013
04-05-2014
04-06-2014
```

And here is my output when i add it to the list.

```
List:
  (Tim He, 000001)
  (Mike rouch, 000002)
  (Luis shin, 000003)
```

which only shows the name and id since thats how i have my toString
How am i able to access the id ex"000001" or "000002" to only print that patients data.

Here is how i am adding the patient data to the node.

```
 protected int numElements;      // number of elements in this list
      protected LLNode<T> currentPos; // current position for iteration

      // set by find method
      protected boolean found;        // true if element found, else false
      protected LLNode<T> location;   // node containing element, if found
      protected LLNode<T> previous;   // node preceeding location

      protected LLNode<T> list;       // first node on the list

      public RefUnsortedList() {
        numElements = 0;
        list = null;
        currentPos = null;
      }

      public void add(T element)//Adds element to this list.
      {
     LLNode<T> prevLoc; //trailing reference
        LLNode<T> location; //traveling reference  

     location = list; //set up search for insertion point
     prevLoc = null;

     while (location != null) //find insertion point
         {  
      prevLoc = location;
      location = location.getLink();
      }

        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element); 
     if (prevLoc == null) //insert node as 1st node
      {
      newNode.setLink(list);
      list = newNode; 
      }
      else
      { 
      newNode.setLink(location);
      prevLoc.setLink(newNode);
      }
      numElements++;
    }
```

Comment: post a snippet of your implementation code so we can get an idea of what you're doing

Comment: Sounds like you should put your patients in a `Map` from id to patient instead of in a `List`.

Comment: added. i just dont know how to access it. :[, i can print out the list. but not 1 of them.

Comment: i havent dont a map before.